# CSS defined background color of FloatingActionButton adds an annoying "hyphen" on top of it

Tags: codenameone

My CN1 app features a `FloatingActionButton`. I need to change its background color. My styles are all defined in CSS. So this one is :

```
FAB {
background-color: #80ccc4;
}
```

And if I create the FAB like `FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_POWER_SETTINGS_NEW, "FAB");` it results in a FloatingActionButton with an added "hyphen" on top of it :
[image]

On the contrary if I create the FAB without providing a style and then programmatically set the background color like `fab.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x80ccc4);` then I get the expected FAB :

[image]

So what should I set in the css file to remove this unwanted "hyphen" ?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are styling `FAB` and not `FloatingActionButton` which is the right UIID for that. If you used `setUIID` that might be problematic on a FAB as the content is set later.

The reason this is happening is a bit of a problem with CSS. We get the background color of the FAB from the `RoundBorder` but transparency should be 0 for the icon in the center.

Unfortunately in CSS you can't express both a background color and 0 background transparency. I don't think this is solvable in the CSS so I'll add a special case to the `FloatingActionButton` that should workaround this.

Comment: Thanks @ShaiAlmog. Does it mean that the "hyphen" is part of the icon in the center ?  And from your first sentence should it be understood that the expected styling would work as expected if I named my css style `FloatingActionButton` ?

Comment: No. I think it's a bug in the FAB that collides with an inherent way the CSS plugin works. We'll fix it for today's update.